# TimeSpan: contar ocorrências de um horário específico

Tags: c#, datetime

Como eu poderia montar esse método que conta as ocorrências de um conjunto de horários específicos em um período?

```
public static int OcorrenciasDeHorarios(
    DateTime Inicio, DateTime Final, params string[] Horarios)
{
    // ??
}
```

Exemplo: se for passado `OcorrenciasDeHorarios(DateTime.Parse("2017-01-10 01:35:00 PM"), DateTime.Parse("2017-01-12 07:35:00 PM"), "12:50:00 AM", "05:50:00 PM");` deve retornar 5, porque ocorre em:

```
2017-01-10 05:50:00 PM

2017-01-11 12:50:00 AM
2017-01-11 05:50:00 PM

2017-01-12 12:50:00 AM
2017-01-12 05:50:00 PM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fiz um Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3QdOb9), mas, antes de usar, é importante explicar alguns aspectos.

Primeiro, é importante observar que passar `string`s de horários não é exatamente a melhor prática, sobretudo porque você vai precisar montar datas dentro da função. Inicialmente fiz uma implementação otimista, a seguir:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

public static IEnumerable<DateTime> OcorrenciasDeHorarios(
    DateTime Inicio, DateTime Final, params string[] Horarios)
{
    var cultura = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    for (var dia = Inicio; dia <= Final; dia = dia.AddDays(1)) 
    {
        foreach (var diaHorario in Horarios.Select(h => DateTime.Parse(dia.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " " + h)))
        {
            if (diaHorario >= Inicio && diaHorario <= Final)
                yield return diaHorario;
        }
    }
}
```

Segundo, repare que não usei `TimeSpan`. `TimeSpan` não é uma estrutura de dados com suporte a *time zones*. Usei `DateTime` mesmo, apenas unindo a lista de horários com as datas que deseja avaliar.

Repare que troquei `int` por `IEnumerable<DateTime>` porque me interessa saber quais foram os resultados obtidos. Feito isso, posso fazer o seguinte:

```
var lista = OcorrenciasDeHorarios(DateTime.Parse("2017-01-10 01:35:00 PM"), DateTime.Parse("2017-01-12 07:35:00 PM"), "12:50:00 AM", "05:50:00 PM");
Console.WriteLine(lista.Count());
foreach (var item in lista) 
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Devolve 5 ocorrências (`lista.Count()`) e imprime a lista de horas com os horários possíveis logo abaixo.

Agora, vamos supor que essa entrada depende de um usuário. Teremos que fazer um algoritmo pessimista, que ficaria assim:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

public static IEnumerable<DateTime> OcorrenciasDeHorarios(
    DateTime Inicio, DateTime Final, params string[] Horarios)
{
    var cultura = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    for (var dia = Inicio; dia <= Final; dia = dia.AddDays(1)) 
    {
        foreach (var diaHorario in Horarios)
        {
            DateTime teste = DateTime.MinValue;
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(dia.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " " + diaHorario, out teste))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Horário " + diaHorario + " está em formato inadequado e não será considerado.");
                continue;
            }

            if (teste >= Inicio && teste <= Final)
                yield return teste;
        }
    }
}
```

[Está neste outro Fiddle aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A4nk5C).